# How to make a UIView scale and remain a square on different screen sizes?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, core-graphics, screen

I am trying to draw a circle using core graphics in a UIView. The UIView is a square, and I've added constraints and everything that should allow it to scale normally on different screen sizes.

However, when I go to a larger screen the circle that is drawn gets stretched vertically, and squished vertically when the screen becomes smaller. The UIView has a 1:1 size ratio when I test different sizes in the XCode editor, but the circle never comes out right in the simulator unless it is the iPhone 7. Any ideas?

Thank you!

For reference, here is my drawing code (inside a UIView subclass for the UIView I have):

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    var rectPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
    UIColor.blue.setFill()
    rectPath.fill()

    var path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
    UIColor.white.setFill()
    path.fill()
}
```

Comment: What are the constraints on your view in the Storyboard?

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of I answered two days ago.Everything you need is spelled out, including a demo project. Hope this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860324/autolayout-contraints-for-a-view-from-xib/42861232#42861232