# IB, Keep ImageView centre, but grow as the screen size, keeping the aspect ratio

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

Since I could do the same thing easily in Android and WPF, I thought XCode's Interface Builder would be easy, too. But I was wrong. I have spent hours on the storyboard resetting the constraints multiple times. I know this question seems stupid, but please give me a hint.

I want something like this on the storyboard. What constraints should I set?

1. The ImageView's aspect ratio should be kept.
2. The ImageView is centred horizontally.
3. The ImageView grows as the screen width, for example 90% of screen width on a vertical phone. Optionally, I wish I could set a maximum, for example, not bigger than say, 400. I mean, 90% on an iPad is too large.
4. The ImageView's top margin should be reasonable to the screen size. I mean, a hard-coded margin 20 would make it too close to the top on an iPad, and a hard-coded margin 200 would look good on an iPad but not on an iPhone SE.

[image]

Comment: Here's an answer (by me) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860324/autolayout-contraints-for-a-view-from-xib/42861232#42861232 - with an associated repo (https://github.com/justdfd/soSquare). This is Swift 3, but the important parts... IB constraints, priorities, etc. should work no matter what. The trick is *multiple* constraints with priorities to let the layout engine know what to break. ALSO, that a "square" `UIView` can be (a) a `UIImageView` with an aspect ratio and (b) can be simply rectangular.

Comment: When it comes to iOS it's not good to stick to the percentage world. Autolayout is not like that and it will bring the trouble sooner than later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Constrain the width and height to keep the aspect ration (one constrain:

   imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.6).isActive = true
2. Constrain the centerX to `viewController`'s view centerX:

   imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
3. Constrain the `imageView` width (or height) to width of the `viewController`'s view using some ratio (90% here):

   imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.9).isActive = true
4. This is the only problem, what is a reasonable offset? Too vague requirement. But if your only problem is to set a proper offset depending on the given UI, I would use size classes to provide different constraints based on the given size class - see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html).

Comment: Aren't they possible with the designer itself, and must I do these programatically? For 4, simply, can I set the top margin as the percentage of the screen, instead of a hard-coded number?

Comment: I do not use storyboards, so I sketched them for you programmatically, but as far as I know, all of those should be creatable using IB.

Comment: Right-dragged the iv and chose Aspect Ratio. Set iv.centerX = centerX, iv.width = 0.9 x width. The width grows, but the height stays the same, distorting the iv. Why isn't the aspect ratio kept?

Comment: @DamnVegetables, you can also use dummy views or layout guides in a situation like this—for example, you could use them to make the computed leading and trailing margins of the image view match the top margin. See the [Auto Layout Guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW53)

Comment: those two constraints you mentioned are #2 and #3, you need one more constraint for #1 - you need to constraint imageView's height to width

Comment: The aspect ratio looks broken on the storyboard, but is kept on the iPhone Simulator, even though they are set to the same iPhone 8 Plus.

Comment: well.. maybe IB have some troubles properly showing it.. although always watch console if there are no ambiguous layout constraints, or some conflicts.. because then it may look good on simulator, but in some other case it may become broken

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this in your storyboard, do the following:

1. Put your imageView at the desired size and position
2. Add Aspect Ratio constraint to your imageView
3. Add center horizontally constraint to your imageView
4. Add width constraint to your imageView equal to its superview's width; then change the Multiplier to `(desired width) / (width of the superview)`. Change the priority to 999
5. Add width constraint to your imageView and set the relation to Less Than or Equal. Put your maximum value here (400)
6. For the top offset, add an UIView with clear background in your superView. Set its top, left and right equal to the top left and right of your superview and add a vertical spacing of 0 to your imageView. Then add a height constraint equal to its superview height and change the Multiplier to `(desired space) / (height of the superview)`. (Its the pink view in the attachment)

[image]