# Autolayout equal spacing and weighted spacing

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm trying to use autolayout to create a layout for cells in my table view. I will attach a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

The main rules are that the button at the bottom must be the width of the cell. Then the image on the left should sit tight to the left but exactly halfway between the top of the entire view and the top of the bottom button. Then I need the 4 rows on the left to sit equally between top of the view and top of the button. And for them to display in a list like they do, and with a small image and text label in line.

I have tried quite a few ways to get this to work. I have managed to get the button to stay at the bottom as required. However, I am struggling to get the imageview to stay as a square on the left and then the 4 rows on the right to take up the rest of the space.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at my answer (and repo written in Swift 3) on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860324/autolayout-contraints-for-a-view-from-xib/42861232#42861232. It may answer part of your question - it creates a *centered* square view in a storyboard. For a variety of reasons I prefer doing constraints in code, so this may not help much but this link discusses `UILayoutGuides` for equal spacing: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/goodbye-spacer-views-hello-layout-guides/

Comment: Is the image showing how you *want* it to look? It doesn't seem to match your description... Shouldn't the "space between Location and Time" be aligned with the center of the image view? And you say *"the image on the left should sit tight to the left"* ... but your image shows it with an indeterminate amount of "padding" on each side?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by wrapping imageView and rows into separate container views (see 
[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBzxQ.png))

**Steps for imageView:**

1. *ContainerView1* constrained to the top of the cell view and to the top of *Check In button*
2. *imageView* constrained vertically to the center of the *ContainerView1*. Also set *imageView* leading constraint to the *ContainerView1* leading as you need

**Steps for rows**

1. Wrap rows into *ContainerView2*. *ContainerView2* constrained to the top of the cell view and to the top of *Check In button*.
2. Constrain *firstRow* top to the top of *ContainerView2*. Each subsequent row should be constrained by its top the previous row's bottom. Constrain *lastRow* bottom to the *ContainerView2* bottom
3. For all rows except *firstRow* drag "equal height" constraint to be equal to the *firstRow* height

That is all!

P.S. if your application works starting with iOS 9.0 you can use UIStackView instead of manual setting constraints in your cell

Answer (score 0):

To keep the images square you need a 1:1 aspect constraint.

Hard to know what else is going wrong with your layout without seeing your constraints but for reference this is how I'd lay out this view.

[image: layout hierarchy]
[image: result]